# Manually adjusted closing price doesn't match with Yahoo Finance Adjusted Price

Tags: r, quantmod

Tried to run the following code in R, but manually adjusted closing price didn't match to the one Yahoo provides. Not that the difference is minor, it's a huge difference. Am I missing something here?

Code below:

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("AAPL")

splits<- getSplits("AAPL")

raw_dividends<- getDividends("AAPL", split.adjust = F)

ratios <- adjRatios(splits = splits, dividends = raw_dividends, close = Cl(AAPL))

aapl_adjusted <- Cl(AAPL) * ratios[, "Split"] * ratios[, "Div"]

head(Ad(AAPL))

head(aapl_adjusted)
```

Comment: can you provide a working example ie gives us some figures and show us the difference, please?

Answer (score 3):

The unadjusted prices from Yahoo are not truly unadjusted.

```r
R> head(AAPL)
##            AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
## 2007-01-03  12.32714  12.36857 11.70000   11.97143   309579900      10.36364
## 2007-01-04  12.00714  12.27857 11.97429   12.23714   211815100      10.59366
## 2007-01-05  12.25286  12.31428 12.05714   12.15000   208685400      10.51822
## 2007-01-08  12.28000  12.36143 12.18286   12.21000   199276700      10.57016
## 2007-01-09  12.35000  13.28286 12.16429   13.22429   837324600      11.44823
## 2007-01-10  13.53571  13.97143 13.35000   13.85714   738220000      11.99609
```

AAPL does not (and did not) trade in prices that include fractions of a cent. So your calculation does not match because you're adjusting for splits twice.

My guess is that Yahoo returns data adjusted for splits, but not dividends. And that can be confirmed by dividing by the split ratio...

```r
R> head(Cl(AAPL) / ratios[,"Split"])
##            AAPL.Close
## 2007-01-03   83.80000
## 2007-01-04   85.66000
## 2007-01-05   85.05000
## 2007-01-08   85.47000
## 2007-01-09   92.57000
## 2007-01-10   96.99999
```

Those prices approximate what you get from other providers. For example, here's what [tiingo](https://www.tiingo.com/) provides. You need a (free) API key to download data from them.

```r
R> head(getSymbols("AAPL", src = "tiingo", api.key = tiingo.key, auto.assign = FALSE))
##            AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume
## 2007-01-03     86.29     86.58    81.90      83.80    44225700
## 2007-01-04     84.05     85.95    83.82      85.66    30259300
## 2007-01-05     85.77     86.20    84.40      85.05    29812200
## 2007-01-08     85.96     86.53    85.28      85.47    28468100
## 2007-01-09     86.45     92.98    85.15      92.57   119617800
## 2007-01-10     94.75     97.80    93.45      97.00   105460000
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Course I was taking, had me confused. Figured out a bit late that Yahoo adjusts only for  raw dividends, not splits.

Comment: How can one recover the "original" OHLC without any adjustments from Yahoo data

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem, Yahoo adjusts only for raw dividends, not split.
Multiplying by dividend ratio got the exact answer for me.

```
> library(quantmod)
> getSymbols("AAPL")
[1] "AAPL"
> splits<- getSplits("AAPL")
> raw_dividends<- getDividends("AAPL", split.adjust = F)
> ratios <- adjRatios(splits = splits, dividends = raw_dividends, close = Cl(AAPL))
> aapl_adjusted <- Cl(AAPL) * ratios[,"Div"]
> head(Ad(AAPL))
           AAPL.Adjusted
2007-01-03      10.36364
2007-01-04      10.59366
2007-01-05      10.51822
2007-01-08      10.57016
2007-01-09      11.44823
2007-01-10      11.99609
> head(aapl_adjusted)
           AAPL.Close
2007-01-03   10.36363
2007-01-04   10.59366
2007-01-05   10.51822
2007-01-08   10.57016
2007-01-09   11.44823
2007-01-10   11.99609
```

Comment: not exactly what they say [here](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN28256.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAJ2885xkBWidQQXRUZrmbgLpyP73riz6Jhm-1Ysuu1-DzukZ7ffXulSoDwibaSGE0CL1xfwuBus0qKg2vy2pr1fThFZD6nT_wgLoQy7Sy8-TEhyaMPtsC9ANzds_E2y1DivqCF0A9OmEevR-VPfBhIXBm_vcl_4-gQ7BeHxbgHqc) though.